# Unexpected Termination of While Loop in Bash

Tags: bash

The below code snippet is for searching files recursively and iterating them.

```
find . -type f -not -name '*.ini' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
   echo "$filename"
done
```

It gives this resut:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

But if I want to process the file somehow like this

```
find . -type f -not -name '*.ini' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
   echo "$filename"
   echo "$(${ExternalApp} -someparams $filename 2> /dev/null| cut -f 2- -d: | cut -f 2- -d ' ' )"
done
```

The loop terminates after the first iteration and result become like this:

```
1.jpg
```

I have recently updated bash (I'm on windows with MSYS). What is the problem here?

Comment: `echo $(some-command)` is an anti-pattern. Just use `some-command`; don't capture the output of a command just to immediately print it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find`'s output is read by the command. This is an especially common problem when using `ssh`, `ffmpeg` or `mplayer`.

You can redirect from `/dev/null` if it doesn't need input at all:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*.ini' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
   echo "$filename"
   #                                            v-- here
   echo "$(${ExternalApp} -someparams $filename < /dev/null 2> /dev/null |
        cut -f 2- -d: | cut -f 2- -d ' ' )"  
done
```